CiviCRM SPARK - Permissions and Drupal roles
I am using CiviCRM SPARK 5.74.4. I am a new user and I would like to have some members who have edit/delete access and others who can just see the data. I implemented the ACL roles and assigned them as in the documentation. However, if I log in as one of the restricted users, I can still edit contacts. I was wondering if this is connected to the roles that I have to assign to users who can login, e.g. "Administrator" and "Staff". Are these Drupal roles with Drupal permissions which override my ACL permissions?
